# SQL error : SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can someone explain why this won't work ? thanks [source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_inline_views.htm)

```
column  "Tablespace" format a13
column  "Used MB"    format 99,999,999
column  "Free MB"    format 99,999,999
column  "Total MB"   format 99,999,999

select
   fs.tablespace_name                          "Tablespace",
   (df.totalspace - fs.freespace)              "Used MB",
   fs.freespace                                "Free MB",
   df.totalspace                               "Total MB",
   round(100 * (fs.freespace / df.totalspace)) "Pct. Free"
from
   (select
      tablespace_name,
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
   from
      dba_data_files
   group by
      tablespace_name
   ) df,
   (select
      tablespace_name,
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) FreeSpace
   from
      dba_free_space
   group by
      tablespace_name
   ) fs
where
   df.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name;
```

Comment: Did you verify that you have access to dba_* tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't have privileges to query the `DBA` tables.

If you are trying to run this as normal user this error will show up.